# GatsbyJS: Preload critical masthead image

Tags: reactjs, image, gatsby, preload, gatsby-image

I am having an issue on my site where my above-the-fold masthead image comes in way too late which makes the site feel slow. The site is built with GatsbyJS where I am using the Gatsby Image plugin as well. I have tried with rel="preload as="image" but this didn't seem to do any difference:

```
<Img
          fluid={
            wpgraphql.imageFile.childImageSharp.fluid
          }
          id="hero__image"
          style={{
            position: "initial"
          }}
          rel="preload"
          as="image"
        />
```

After reading the Gatbsy Image documentation I found that `loading="eager"` could make a difference as well. I therefore have tried adding the loading="eager" but still my masthead image is one of the last things to be discovered in my waterfall.

How can I make my masthead image load critical and come in earlier in my waterfall?

Comment: Which plugin are you using to fetch the images?

Comment: I am using WPGraphQL & gatsby-source-graphql for a headless WordPress build. I am the method described by Henrik here as well: https://dev.to/nevernull/gatsby-with-wpgraphql-acf-and-gatbsy-image-72m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby Image uses a low-quality preview image in the `src` and delays the switch from this preview image to the full-size image until Gatsby is initialized client-side (which happens after React hydrates). For this reason it's never going to be particularly performant for above-the-fold content. I recommend using the `srcSet` data that comes back from the query you have now directly:

```
<img
  srcSet={wpgraphql.imageFile.childImageSharp.fluid.srcSet}
  alt=""
  loading="eager"
/>
```

From here you can style it to match your desired output.